# PhpStorm compile Less folder to style.css

Tags: css, compilation, less, phpstorm

I have a folder with Less files, split in parts to have a cleaner workspace. But I want them to be compiled by PhpStorm to 1 file (`styles.css` in a `css` folder). I installed `lessc` and it compiles the files separate. See picture 1

[image]

As I said I would like to have all files combined into `css/styles.css` But I don't get this configured right. My configuration is as followed:

[image]

I hope someone can explain what arguments I could use.

Comment: Since I don´t work with less I can only guess:
how do your lessfiles look like? do you have 1main lessfile which includes the others? That would be my guess in the dark.

Comment: Yes I work with 1 main sheet that includes all others. I got it working now tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **Track only root files** option is enabled in **Less** file watcher settings, file watcher produces a single `.css` file with name matching your "main" `.less` file (the one that imports all your "partials") that includes the merged content of all your `.less` files. No individual `.css` files for partials are created